# Kendo input custom validation

Tags: validation, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo grid that has some inputs like FirstNam, LastName and Email. I also have a custom rule for the Validator to check for "Space" as input and return false.

However, when the user inputs space the validator executes and returns false and shows me the error message but my save function still goes through even though the validator returned false.

What am I doing wrong here?

FirstName: { type: "string", validation: { required: { message: "First name is required" } } },
    LastName: { type: "string", validation: { required: { message: "Last name is required" } } },
Email: { type: "string", validation: { required: { message: "Email is required" } } },

```
 $("#userGrid").kendoValidator({
        rules: {
            required: function (input) {
                if (input.filter("[required]").length && $.trim(input.val()) == "") {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is the question here? is the question about why your validator doesn't accept the space character or is it about why your save function goes through with an invalid input?

Comment: @Philr, why my save function goes through when the validator returns false. space is an invalid input

Comment: Try adding in your if statement && input.is("class or id name of the input you want to validate")

Comment: Tried it didn't work, so i changed the validation in-line via the demo in the kendo site and it worked. Thanks for your help.